# Xamarin, ListView Update

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have a question about the update of the ListVIew, Xamarin.

Hello.

He is currently studying Xamarin.
What I'm trying to create now is like an item update to Listview.

There is a ListView item called  TX 1.
When you press TX 1 here, 
TX 1 --- > TX 2 --- > TX 3 --- > TX 1 This is how we call up different events.

Here's my code now.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ArrayAdapter<string> lstAdapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        int _Position = 0;
        string[] _Test_ListView_tow = { "TX1", "TX2", "TX3" };
        string[] _Set_RD_Data = { _Test_ListView_tow[_Position], "Display" };

        ListView _Test_ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id._Test_ListView);
        lstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, _Set_RD_Data);
        _Test_ListView.Adapter = lstAdapter;


        _Test_ListView.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            switch(e.Position)
            {
                case 0:
                    if(_Position < 2)
                    {
                        _Position++;
                        _Set_RD_Data[0] = _Test_ListView_tow[_Position];
                        lstAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                        Console.WriteLine("Data : " + _Set_RD_Data[0].ToString());
                        Toast.MakeText(this, _Set_RD_Data[0] + "Select", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    else if (_Position == 2)
                    {
                        _Position = 0;
                        _Set_RD_Data[0] = _Test_ListView_tow[_Position];
                        lstAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                        Console.WriteLine("Data : " + _Set_RD_Data[0].ToString());
                        Toast.MakeText(this, _Set_RD_Data[0] + "Select", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

How do we do that?
The current situation, as a result of the Toast, changes content, data.
But it doesn't change what ListView says.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Remove()` and `Insert()` to update the item.

First, change the type of `_Set_RD_Data` form `string[]` to `List<string>`. Then you could call the `Remove()` and `Insert()` method to manipulate the data in the adapter. Remove the `_Set_RD_Data[0]` from the adapter, and then modify the `_Set_RD_Data[0]` value. Finally, insert it back to the adapter at index 0.

Here is the  code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    ArrayAdapter<string> lstAdapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        int _Position = 0;
        string[] _Test_ListView_tow = { "TX1", "TX2", "TX3" };
        List<string> _Set_RD_Data = new List<string>() { _Test_ListView_tow[_Position], "Display" };

        ListView _Test_ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id._Test_ListView);
        lstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, _Set_RD_Data);
        _Test_ListView.Adapter = lstAdapter;

        _Test_ListView.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            switch (e.Position)
            {
                case 0:
                    if (_Position < 2)
                    {
                        _Position++;
                        lstAdapter.Remove(_Set_RD_Data[0]);
                        _Set_RD_Data[0] = _Test_ListView_tow[_Position];
                        lstAdapter.Insert(_Set_RD_Data[0], 0);
                        Toast.MakeText(this, _Set_RD_Data[0] + "Select", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    else if (_Position == 2)
                    {
                        _Position = 0;
                        lstAdapter.Remove(_Set_RD_Data[0]);
                        _Set_RD_Data[0] = _Test_ListView_tow[_Position];
                        lstAdapter.Insert(_Set_RD_Data[0], 0);                            
                        Toast.MakeText(this, _Set_RD_Data[0] + "Select", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the result is:
[image]